# Get all selected="selected" values and put into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get all options with a `selected="selected"` attribute on a page.

There are many of these instances on the page but I can only seem to save the first to an array.

How the `selected="selected"` shows up:

```
<select bind-event-change="disableHiddenInputs()" bind="appliesToResource6" id="link_list_links__link_type" name="link_list[links][][link_type]">
<option value="frontpage">Store Frontpage</option>
<option selected="selected" value="collection">Collection</option>
<option value="product">Product</option>
<option value="catalog">All Products</option>
<option value="page">Page</option>
<option value="blog">Blog</option>
<option value="search">Search page</option>
<option value="http">Web Address</option>
</select>
```

What I have tried :

```
$('#link_list_links__link_type option:selected').map(function () {

return $(this).val();
});
```

It only returns the first `selected="selected"` option and not the rest of the iterations.

How do I return all of the options on the page with `selected="selected"`?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the id you have used, [ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) of an element must be unique, so when you use id-selector it will return only the first element with the said id. which means `#link_list_links__link_type` selects only 1 select element thus you are getting only one value.

> A unique identifier for the element.
>  There must not be multiple
>   elements in a document that have the same id value.

One solution here is to use a class to group similar elements so

```
<select bind-event-change="disableHiddenInputs()" bind="appliesToResource6"         name="link_list[links][][link_type]" class="link_list_links__link_type">
```

then

```
var array = $('.link_list_links__link_type option:selected').map(function () {
return $(this).val();
}).get();
```